# Take use of the native spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, rotation, spinner, android-animation

I want to rebuild (maybe I don't even have to) the [nativ android progress indicator](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/android-drawables/1.6/spinner_black_76.png) and show it as icon for a list item. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032304/android-imageview-animation) and endet up with a heavy performance eating animation, which also doesn't match the native spinner. The code has as "LinearInterpolator" which seems to cause those problems.

Now I made my own Interpolar and fulfilled one of my needs: It's quantizing the steps into 12.

However, I still have huge performance problems. **The UiThread now doesnt let my background threads run**, which are intended to download and parse data. Note the fact, that I am displaying several spinners in a list. I also tried to set the interpolator as class variable in my listAdapter. So, all listViews can take use of this Interpolator.

```
if(imageViewIcon != null) {
  RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 51f, 51f);
  anim.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation( float input ) {
      return (float) Math.floor((double)input*10)/12;
    }
  });
 // anim
  anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  anim.setDuration(1000);


  // Start animating the image
  imageViewSpinner.startAnimation(anim);


}
```

**Update**

Finally I found the ProgressBarWidget which does exactly the same as I do. However, it's still not very performant. (It's better though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the widget "[ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)". The simplest version is that round spinner