# Android UI: What is a good tutorial or resource for image/icon transition animation

Tags: android-layout, android

I have seen fancy icon transition animations for loading or waiting for process to finish.  The icons transitions have splash animations or something similar to animated gifs and then some actual explode like effect on finish loading for a resource in the Android App.

I would like to find tutorial or resources to help me develop these button, icon, small image, transition animations. I really need some help on this, please help.

Please help me with your knowledge on learning or sample code or resources on learning to implement these things for Android UI.  thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer help you ? If so, it would be nice to _accept_ it, by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [TransitonDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html), apply it to your `ImageView`, and you've got a nice transition. There is a tutorial for that [here](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.ie/2013/02/android-beginner-tutorial-part-88.html).

If you want more advanced stuff like movement or [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032304/android-imageview-animation), look at the [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) sample app on GitHub. There is also a tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html).

You can also use [GifImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) if you want to display a GIF animation.

Comment: what about those animated gifs?  should i just use an actual animated gif for the "loading" animated icons for loading indicators?

Comment: @YoungBrogrammer , You can use [GifImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) library to do that.