# Rotating wheel in android

Tags: android, rotation, android-animation, android-imageview

My imageview consists of circle wheel  as shown in below pic.I want that wheel should start rotating as soon as user presses a start button and stop rotating when user presses stop button.Is it possible programmatically?If yes,how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Possibly Duplicate Que : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032304/android-imageview-animation

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @BojanKseneman yupp.correct answer..thankuu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file named **clockwise_rotation.xml** and put it into `/res/anim` Change the duration according to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    />
```

And make these two functions that you will be calling in your two buttons

```
private void startAnimation(){
    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
    mImageView.startAnimation(rotation);
}

private void stopAnimation(){
    mImageView.clearAnimation();
}
```